# I can't start ssh agent in windows in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, ssh-agent

I need to configure ssh on *Windows* for an *Angular* project that has dependencies that are being accessed with *ssh*. I have already generated the keys with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` but... when I go to enable the `ssh-agent` service in *PowerShell* by running:

```
Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
```

I get the following error:

```
Set-Service : No se puede configurar el servicio 'OpenSSH Authentication Agent (ssh-agent)' 
debido al error siguiente:
Acceso denegado
En línea: 1 Carácter: 25
+ Get-Service ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: 
(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Servi
ce], ServiceCommandException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotSetService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Did you try in an elevated powershell (aka as Admin)?

Comment: Launch `powershell.exe` elevated (Win+X -> A, or right-click -> "Run as Administrator")

Comment: aah already, running powershell as administrator worked for me. 
Thanks!!!